# Does this MMX mem copy code need a fence?

Tags: assembly, memory-fences, mmx

This basic mmx memory copy code corrupts memory in release mode, but only with certain compilers.  Visual Studio 2010 in specific.  I think it's because this code needs a memory fence, but I'm not sure where it would go or exactly why.  This code worked perfectly with Visual Studio 2005.

```
MMXMemCopy PROC dest:PTR BYTE, src:PTR BYTE, len:DWORD
  mov edi, dest
  mov esi, src
  mov ecx, len
  shr ecx, 6             //divide len by 64
  mov edx, ecx
  shl edx, 6
  mov eax, len
  sub eax, edx
  or  ecx, 0
  jz  lastbytes         //if < 64 bytes, copy 8 bytes at a time

copynext:             //copies 64 bytes
  movq   mm0, mmword ptr [esi]
  movq   mm1, mmword ptr [esi + 8h]
  movq   mm2, mmword ptr [esi + 10h]
  movq   mm3, mmword ptr [esi + 18h]
  movq   mm4, mmword ptr [esi + 20h]
  movq   mm5, mmword ptr [esi + 28h]
  movq   mm6, mmword ptr [esi + 30h]
  movq   mm7, mmword ptr [esi + 38h]
  movntq mmword ptr [edi], mm0
  movntq mmword ptr [edi + 8h], mm1
  movntq mmword ptr [edi + 10h], mm2
  movntq mmword ptr [edi + 18h], mm3
  movntq mmword ptr [edi + 20h], mm4
  movntq mmword ptr [edi + 28h], mm5
  movntq mmword ptr [edi + 30h], mm6
  movntq mmword ptr [edi + 38h], mm7

  add esi, 40h
  add edi, 40h
  dec ecx
  jnz copynext

lastbytes:                //copies last 8 bytes
  or eax, 0
  jz finished
  movq mm0, mmword ptr [esi]
  movntq mmword ptr [edi], mm0
  add esi, 8h
  add edi, 8h
  sub eax, 8h
  jmp lastbytes

finished:
  emms
  ret
```

MMXMemCopy ENDP

Comment: Can `src` and `dest` overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `esi` and `edi` are callee-saved. I think you also need `sfence` for memory ordering.

Comment: A fence wouldn't be needed if `src` and `dest` don't overlap, right?

Comment: The problem was esi and edi were not being saved.  Thanks a lot for the help.